# How Can I specified the object of my precedent form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In my project I want to use the object created by my precedent form:

Here is the schema of my database:

[image: my database]

My QuizController

```
public function creation(Request $request){
        $quiz = new Quiz();
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $formQuiz = $this->createForm(QuizType::class, $quiz);

        $formQuiz->handleRequest($request);
  

        if ($formQuiz->isSubmitted() && $formQuiz->isValid() ) {
            $quiz->setCreatedAt(new DateTimeImmutable());
            $quiz->setCreatedBy($user);
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($quiz);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('creation_questions');
        }
        return $this->render('quiz/creation.html.twig', [
            'formQuiz' => $formQuiz->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

And my QuestionController that must be connected with the quiz form

```
public function creation_questions(Request $request){
        $quiz = ?
        $question = new Questions();

        $formQuestions = $this->createForm(QuestionType::class, $question);
        
        $formQuestions->handleRequest($request);

        if ($formQuestions->isSubmitted() && $formQuestions->isValid() ) {
            $question->setCreatedAt(new DateTimeImmutable());
            $question->setQuiz($quiz);
 
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($question);
  
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }
        return $this->render('questions/questions.html.twig', [
            'formQuestion' => $formQuestions->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

What do I have to write in place of the '?'?

Comment: Hello, you should send your quiz from creation method to creation_questions like any other parameter, Or you can send your quiz id to creation_questions and fetch Quiz again. Or directly create questions under the creation action.

Comment: Yes, I'll take the 2nd option but I as I'm a new user I don't have the synthax. Is it like return $this->redirectToRoute('creation_questions', [
                $id -> $quiz->getId()
            ]); ?

Comment: Look into database [relationships](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html). In your case you could do a [OneToMany](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#the-manytoone-onetomany-association) relation. So each User can have many quizzes. This way you will have methods in your entity like: `$user->getQuizzes() or $user->addQuiz()` etc..

Comment: As already mentioned by Julien B, it looks like you need to add Quiz ID to your `creation_questions` route, since you're redirecting to it **after** persisting a newly created quiz in the database. `return $this->redirectToRoute('creation_questions', ['id' => $quiz->getId()]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your routing but you could use paramConverte "magic" from SensioFrameworkExtraBundle and do something like this.

```
/**
 * @Route("/some-route/{id}", name="some_route_name")
 */
public function creation_questions(Request $request, Quiz $quiz)
{
    $question = new Questions();

    $formQuestions = $this->createForm(QuestionType::class, $question);

    $formQuestions->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formQuestions->isSubmitted() && $formQuestions->isValid()) {
        $question->setCreatedAt(new DateTimeImmutable());
        $question->setQuiz($quiz);

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($question);

        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }
    return $this->render('questions/questions.html.twig', [
        'formQuestion' => $formQuestions->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Where the `{id}` part of `/someRoute/{id}` is the Quiz Id. Symfony should automagically fetch the Quiz matching that id. Or you can be more explicit about how the param converter should interpret such a value. More info here https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html

Alternatively, you could pass the quiz id and fetch the quiz manually (less magic but totally legit).

```
/**
 * @Route("/some-route/{id}", name="some_route_name")
 */
public function creation_questions(Request $request, int $id)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $quiz = $entityManager->getRepository(Quiz::class)->find($id);
    $question = new Questions();

    $formQuestions = $this->createForm(QuestionType::class, $question);

    $formQuestions->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formQuestions->isSubmitted() && $formQuestions->isValid()) {
        $question->setCreatedAt(new DateTimeImmutable());
        $question->setQuiz($quiz);

        $entityManager->persist($question);

        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }
    return $this->render('questions/questions.html.twig', [
        'formQuestion' => $formQuestions->createView()
    ]);
}
```